# Function is not working when passed as a prop to the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, jsx

In my parent component(App.js) i am passing a function as a prop to the child:

```
import React from "react";
import Win from "./components/Win"

function App() {

  const [squares, setSquares] = React.useState(dices)
  const [allSame, setAllSame] = React.useState(false)

  function Reset() {
    console.log("yes")
  }

  return (
          <Win onClick = {() => Reset} />
}

export default App;
```

this is my child component(Win.js):

```
import React from "react"
import reset from "../images/reset.png"
import Confetti from "./Confetti"

export default function Win(props) {
    // function r(){
    //     console.log("lol")
    // }

    return (
        <div className="Win">
            {/* <Confetti /> */}
            <h1  style={{color:"white", fontSize:"4rem"}}>You Won</h1>
                <button onClick={() => props.Reset}>Press ME</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

i made the function r just for testing and tried using it when the button is clicked, it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: `<Win onClick = {() => Reset} />` the only member of `props` here is  `onClick`.  There is no `props.Reset`

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the function inside the arrow function. Use `()` to invoke it. Also, the name of the prop passed to the child is `onClick`, not `Reset`.

```
<button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>
<Win onClick = {() => Reset()} />
```

Alternatively, directly pass the function reference itself to `onClick`.

```
<button onClick={props.onClick}>
<Win onClick={Reset} />
```

Comment: I did this and now it showing me an error saying that props.Reset is not a function

Comment: @student Sorry, I missed that you passed it as `onClick`, so it should be `props.onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

`Reset` is a simple function, let's write it as `() => console.log("yes")`.

In the `onClick` property of `Win` you wrap it in a function, so we have `<Win onClick={() => () => console.log("yes")} />`.

In the `onClick` property of `button` you wrap it in a function once again, so now we have `<button onClick={() => () => () => console.log("yes")} />`.

So while you want to pass a function that prints to console, you pass a function that returns a function that returns a function that prints to console.

Since you start with a function that prints to console, you should simply pass it without wrapping in new functions.

```js
<Win onClick={Reset} />
<button onClick={props.onClick}>
```

Also, from `App` you pass the property with the name `onClick` while in `Win` you try to read it as `Reset`. Change it to one of them.